# E: Package 'curl' has no installation candidate

Tags: ubuntu, curl

I am trying to install nodejs in ubuntu and I need to use curl but it does not allow me to install curl
it shows me this error every time I try to install it

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package curl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'curl' has no installation candidate

I tryied to update but error is the same all the time

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/us.archive.ubuntu.com/archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and then do `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install curl`

You can also install node like this

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

Comment: Have you tried using "sudo apt install nodejs" and it doesn't work either?